# Sqlite Query how to get the all the entry from the year

Tags: sqlite, datetime

I need to get all the entries in a sqlite database that match the current year? how do I do that do I that.

Here is my code but it's return 0

My table structure looks like this:

```
id | name | tt_date
____________________
1  | test1 | {ts '2016-02-11 00:00:00'}
2  | test2 | {ts '2016-02-11 00:00:00'}
```

Here is my query:

```
select * FROM tt WHERE strftime('%Y', tt_date) = strftime('%Y', 'now')
```

but it returns 0 in the reults

Comment: What is that `{ts` stuff? What format do the timestamps actually have?

Comment: because I am using java and coldfusion it's easier to parse that way but it could be in a different format, if it would make it easier with the query part. The Coldfusion and Java code are all written and tested I just need to work with the query.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use the [built-in date/time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), you must use one of the [supported date/time formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime). In other words, drop the `{ts ''}`.